# visualvm hangs on mac 0S10.8

Tags: java, osx-mountain-lion, visualvm

VisualVm hangs when started from either the downloaded visualvm.dmg or the zip.  It gets to the Visual VM Calibration dialog and then stops. There are no messages in the dialog box nor does clicking the OK button do anything.
I can't find any log in either my home or the extracted zip folder when I run either.

From the command line I get

> ./visualvm
>   Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.7.0_10+".
>   Found jdkhome=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Any advice on how to diagnose the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's telling you that you don't have a JDK/JRE with a version of 7 or higher. If you didn't install one, then it won't be there - download it from the oracle website, or install the Open JDK if you require version 7 or higher.

You should also be able to see error messages in the OS X console (but I doubt you'll get more detailed error messages than you already received)

[Oracle link to install JRE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jre.html)

Comment: The docs state that JDK 6 is the minimum requirement but the Apple jdk doesn't have jvisualvm in the bin. I had not wanted to install the apple update to 7 as Chrome would stop working. I have now downloaded the JDK direct from oracle and it works. It's annoying that apple don't supply it.

Comment: To be honest I think things have improved a lot since Oracle took over supplying the JDK/JREs, the loss of the tight integration was a small price to pay to get the most up-to-date releases simultaneously with all other platforms, and as you discovered Apple didn't include a number of elements that were standard on other platfoms, e.g. Derby (Java DB).

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, just resize the screen and you'll see the "I agree" button.

Or, add the "--laf Metal" arg to the startup of the application.

Hope it works for you, too!